# opencv build problem ("_cvLoadImage", referenced from)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, opencv

I am trying to integrate opencv into my project and I am having problems. I have installed opencv on my mac and have added libopencv_imgproc.dylib, libopencv_highgui.dylib and libopencv_core.dylib which i am instructed to do so by this webiste :-

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port

under the title :-

Using the OpenCV libraries in an Xcode OS X project (opencv 2.1 since SVN r3060)

The header search paths has also been set and that does  not seem to be an issue as I am able to import the individual header files.

However when i try to build the project I am getting this error:-

"_cvLoadImage", referenced from:

that is associated with:-

IplImage *imagetest = cvLoadImage("background.png",1);

Now I am beginning to think it may be to do with the operating system (32 or 64 bit) or the version of opencv/xcode but I am unsure.

The project is for an iPhone/ipodTouch and is therefore in objective c.

Has anybody had this problem? and if so how was it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also want to link `libopencv_legacy` for `IplImage` stuff (which is replaced by `CvMat`).